# After registration using tank_auth user should get logged in for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the best authentication out there for codeigniter, I decided to use tank_auth.
It seems to be the best authentication for codeigniter.

So how can I, after registration user using tank_auth should be automatically logged in  without requiring him/her to activate his/her account.

I have 4 step of registration process in my application so I need to add the user id into multiple tables. 
My Logice like at first step I want to I will directly login to user and then session id will be useful to other step.

Answer (score 0):

> My Logice like at first step I want to I will directly login to user
>   and then session id will be useful to other step.

Having never used Tank_auth, I'm not sure how to implement this into their system, however it shouldn't be too difficult.
Here's a quick example I whipped up, just for you...

```
$data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $hashed_password
);

$query = $this->db->insert('users', $data);

// Use this for each table
$user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Then you can do whatever with the database, linking the user by their id `$user_id`

The session can be set once you have this ID

Comment: but I was using the tank auth library its quite dificult to manage and pass the ID.